# How is data typically reloaded/displayed on a device when only a tiny amount of data changes after updating the database? (Conceptually)

Tags: ios, arrays, database, core-data

Here's and example of what I am talking about:

Take Twitter for iOS. Whenever you tweet, the tweet is sent to the database, and then it is also displayed on your device as part of the list of tweets.

**How is the list of tweets that you see on your device updated after just sending one tweet?** Here are some possible ways that I thought of how it could be done, but what Im asking for is which one is the best method of doing so:

- **The whole list of recent Tweets is re-downloaded from the remote Twitter server after sending a tweet** (I highly doubt this, as this would take a relatively long time, when it really is just appending one Tweet to the array of Tweets displayed)
- **The local array that holds the Tweet objects is updated separately from the database** (For example, it updates the database, and then updates its array with the same data you sent to the database, and never downloads the Tweet you just sent since you don't need to, because you already have it locally, since you composed it)
- **Is Core Data capable of updating the remote data server AND the array all in one (or relatively few) step(s)?** (Sorry, if this is the obvious answer and if it sounds like I didn't look into it, but I did read about Core Data and started a tutorial. Its just that there is so much content that it would take me a whole day or two just to figure out if its appropriate for my application)
- **Is there an alternative way of managing this?**

**Also, if its one of the latter two ideas above, are you able to update the table view cells by just updating the local array and reloading the cells from that array without loading your one tweet from the database?** I'm just curious about what would be the most efficient way of doing this.

**So again, my main question reworded is: how do you keep data that you sent to a remote database and the local data (stored in a mutable array) in sync whenever you do a tiny single update (such as sending a Tweet) without having to reload all of the data from the database (when there is other content [i.e. other Tweets]) already loaded.**

(I am aware that no one except Twitter developers know exactly how Twitter actually done, but I'm just using this Twitter functionality as an example. This same concept could be applied to any similar app.)

(Also, this is a conceptual question about dataflow, so I don't need to see any code, but suggestions to use different technologies like Core Data, or just updating an array will be appreciated.)

(I've been looking into this, and all the different ways of doing it, and it is becoming very time consuming, so I figured to ask you guys who have experience. Additionally, this could help someone else who has similar questions.)

(Sorry if it looks like I'm asking a bunch of questions, but I'm basically asking the same question in different ways, and offering possible solutions.)

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to analyze the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immutable messages like tweets are actually quite easy to handle -- server side, and in your app.

When you send a tweet from your client to the server, you also update your "main context" (see "Managed Object Context") which in turn sends notifications to your controller (see `NSFetchedResultsController` which in turns updates your table view according your local model residing in the Managed Object Context.

Updating from the server is just merging the local tweets with the new ones added in the meantime.

Since there is no mutable tweet, synchronization is really no big deal. As mentioned in the comment, if there were mutable tweets (or any kind of messages) the synchronization will become *much more* complex.

Core Data will NOT automatically update a remote server. But there are solutions to "view" a remote database through Core Data - see NSIncrementalStore and a related third party libraries (AFIncrementalStore).

Answer (score 1):

This is ridiculously trivial. You update your local database and send off the remote update at the same time.

You use the remote response to mark your local record as synched or try updating again later.

Comment: Well, it is only "ridiculous trivial" because the tweets are immutable. Otherwise, it would become _extraordinary complex_ where even whole companies (did I say Apple?) struggle to get it right.

Comment: @Couch Maybe you are thinking about philosophical question, such as the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) framework to describe databases. But the thought of getting all tweets to confirm if the last one has arrived is ludicrous.

Comment: No, no ACID - but "eventual consistent" which becomes a factor when the tweets can be edited by everyone at any time - that is, when they are not immutable. Then, synchronization becomes complex.